# Xdebug Chrome preview not rendering the response properly, shows one line only

Tags: php, google-chrome, xdebug

Chrome preview does not render the response properly, since yesterday when I upgraded the work machine from Win 8 to Win 10. Please see the screenshots:

[image]

[image]

As you can see, only one line of the object is rendered, when I tried it with a simple array, same thing happened, it only rendered the word "array" and "0";

I'm using Chrome 72.0.3626.96, WampServer64 with PHP 7.2.14 and those are my Xdebug settings in php.ini:

```
zend_extension="c:/wamp64/bin/php/php7.2.14/zend_ext/php_xdebug-2.6.1-7.2-vc15-x86_64.dll"

xdebug.default_enable=1
html_errors = On
xdebug.remote_host = 127.0.0.1
xdebug.remote_enable = 1
xdebug.remote_port = 9123
xdebug.profiler_enable = off
xdebug.profiler_enable_trigger = off
xdebug.profiler_output_name = cachegrind.out.%t.%p
xdebug.profiler_output_dir ="c:/wamp64/tmp"
xdebug.show_local_vars=0
xdebug.var_display_max_depth = 10
xdebug.var_display_max_children = 256
xdebug.var_display_max_data = 1024
```

It worked literally a day ago before I got Windows 10. Chrome bug or am I doing something wrong?

Comment: You can have a look here : https://github.com/arif2009/Installing-Xdebug-for-XAMPP

Comment: @Arif I moved away from XAMPP as it doesn't offer multiple PHP installations and I feel that WAMP is generally superior and more convenient.

Comment: It seems like the preview doesn't render var_dump past `<font>` tag in multiple tests. Any ideas?

Comment: FYI, I experienced this issue yesterday in Chrome on my macbook at work. It seems it is possibly a bug in the latest version of Chrome. I have Chrome version 72.0.3626.119 and macOS 10.13.4 and xdebug enabled.

Comment: So I tried to reproduce this issue and I noticed something interesting. I noticed that in my case and your case, the preview tab is stopping at the `<font>` tag. I tried hardcoding a `echo '<font>test test test</font>';` before the `var_dump` and it printed fine. However, when I tried to do `echo "<font color='#888a85'>=&gt;</font>";` which is the exact string from `var_dump` (including the color attribute), the preview stopped rendering. So something about the font tag with color attribute is causing Chrome inspector to "crash".

Comment: The mystery deepens, even when I use `ini_set('html_errors', 0);` which should disable html output from `var_dump`, the preview tab still cuts off after the first line.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the issue and it is quite bizarre. It looks like the latest version of Chrome (72.0.3626.119 for me) has problems rendering the preview when the response text has a hash character (#) in the output. It will happily render everything until it encounters the hash character. This is most definitely a bug in Chrome.

I discovered this by first noticing that the preview stops at `<font color='#888a85'>=&gt;</font>`. I hardcoded this in the document and removed characters until I concluded that the hash character was causing the problem.

Here is a demo of the bug. When you run this snippet in the latest version of Chrome and with Inspector open, you should see the request pop up in the network tab. When you click on the request and go to the preview tab, the third paragraph is cut off since there is a `#` right before it.

```html
<p>Para1</p>
<p>Para2</p>
#
<p>Para3</p>
```

<s>I was unable to find an open bug report regarding this so I took the liberty of reporting it here: https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=936284</s>

It looks like this issue has already been reported ([link](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=930061)) and fixed in the dev version of Chrome but hasn't been updated in the stable version yet.

In the meantime, if you really need to have var_dump work in Chrome, you can do this as a workaround (buffer the output and replace instances of `#`):

```
ob_start();
var_dump($var);
echo str_replace('#','',$ob_get_clean());
```

... or you can just turn off HTML errors:

```
ini_set('html_errors', false);
```

Comment: I will try and install the dev Chrome when I get to work today to double check this but it seems like you might have found the answer !

Comment: Yes, works perfectly fine with Chrome Canary. Thank you for your help investigating this issue, I for some reason did not consider the possibility of Chrome bug being the reason for this.